# Python String to dateTime conversion

Tags: python

I have a string like

```
a = "datetime.datetime(2009,04,01)"
```

I would like to convert this to a datetime object in python. How should I proceed?

Comment: How many other types of strings are there? Is datetime.datetime the only one, or do other class names appear?

Comment: import datetime and then date = eval(a)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code in the previous answer would work, but using `eval` is considered risky, because an unexpected input could have disastrous consequences. ([Here](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)'s more info on why `eval` can be dangerous.)

A better option here is to use Python's `strptime` method:

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime_string = "datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 31)"
format = "datetime.datetime(%Y, %m, %d)"
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(datetime_string, format)
```

There are lots of different formats you can use for parsing datetimes from strings. You may want to check out the docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Comment: I prefer this code over `eval` also because it's clear about exactly what it's trying to do. With `eval`, you would have to read the surrounding code to understand what's happening, which can make debugging hard later on.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That fixed it!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval`

```
eval('datetime.datetime(2009, 1, 1)')
```

You'll have to make sure `datetime` is imported first

```
>>> import datetime
>>> d = datetime.datetime(2009, 1, 1)
>>> repr(d)
'datetime.datetime(2009, 1, 1, 0, 0)`
>>> eval(repr(d))
datetime.datetime(2009, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Worth noting: https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Well, running any untrusted code is dangerous, with or without `eval`.  It's just that historically `eval`-type functionality has been used to run arbitrary statements from users.  There really just aren't many use cases for `eval`.  If you're using it, there's probably a much better and safer way to do what you want to accomplish without `eval`.

Comment: Nope. With `datetime.strptime`, the worst that can happen is that you get a wrong month/day. With `eval`, you could lose control of your server.

Answer (score -1):

you could use eval. eval lets run python code within python program

```
a = "datetime.datetime(2009,04,01)" 
import datetime
a = eval(a)
print a
print type(a)
```

will result in

```
2009-04-01 00:00:00
<type 'datetime.datetime'>
```